# Migrate Drupal Content Type to Wordpress

Tags: drupal, wordpress, content-type, podscms

My Old site is developed in Drupal which is having a Content Type to create a form and the user is able to view that form and submit the form.  The form is added as a new page in Drupal so that the page can be provate or user can make it public based on his wish.  The form has File upload, Image upload, Text area with TineyMCE editor also radio button.

I need to replicate this feature in Wordpress.  I researched in Google and found out there is no default way of doing it.  People suggest Pods, I am not familiar with pods and I could not achieve the feature.  Also I saw another plugin Custom Field Template Which I cannot view the form in UI so that the user can input.  It is avilable for admin.

Please guide me how to achieve this feature in Wordpress.

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT : 
Finally I did by http://formidablepro.com/ formidable pro plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Pods to be pretty clunky, since it uses a lot of non-core WordPress features.

The various Custom Field plugins work okay, but they are essentially just text fields, so you can't really attach images very well (you just have to paste the full url). This might not be an issue for you, but if you're handing this website off to a client, I'd avoid this.

The best plugin I've found is Magic Fields: http://magicfields.org/

- It allows you to create 15 different types of Custom Fields, including image, multiline, checkbox, audio, file, color picker, date picker, drop down, etc.
- Latest version now uses core WordPress features like Custom Post Types and Taxonomies, which gives you better plugin compatibility and more stable updates.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..  The form looks good however,  I want the form to be user posting a from.  I was not able to display the form to the user and let the user submit the form.  I can only be able to view the form as a widget in my post.  Please help me Chris.

Comment: How to display magic fields in UI to enter a post..  I tired a lot and the registered user is not able to see the magicfields while adding a post  only admin is able to see the post.  Please help..

Comment: Oh, you can use Gravity Forms (paid plugin) to make a form on the front end of the website that populates a post on the backend. I did that for this website: http://recipes.americanspice.com/submit-a-recipe/ Once a user submits a recipe, it creates a Magic Fields post in draft mode, which you can then approve to make it live.

Comment: THank you Chris,  I saw that plugin.  Worst case I have to go to Gravity Forms.  Currently I am trying to code to make that widget available in the UI for the user to submit.  The problem is I am not that good in php..:) In Magic Forms they are using __construct method in mf_post I am trying to call that method and print the post in UI.  Thanks for all your help..

Answer (score 2):

As part of my freelancing work I encountered [gConverter](http://gconverter.com/), and used it to convert from bbpress to Drupal.
While I don't have experience with converting from Drupal to WordPress, gConverter servie was amazing, and they promise to support Drupal-toWordpress as well.
Since their service is not too expensive, and since they ask payment only after successful migration - I believe it is a perfect solution.
Regards,
Shushu

Comment: Thank you Shushu.. I will have your option.  If I cannot do it.  I will consider your option..  Thank you very much.

Comment: For professional help you can also check http://migratetowp.com/ specialized in Drupal to Wordpress conversions

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it myself but these two very recent plug-ins for custom types and views look promising http://wpml.org/2011/09/multilingual-ready-custom-types-and-fields-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the reply..  I saw this plugin also..  it seams this aslo have the same limitation..  That fields cannot be user submittable post.